# pg_dump and pg_restore between different servers with a selection criteria on the data to be dumped

Tags: python, database, postgresql, schema, psql

Currently trying to use pg_dump and pg_restore to be able to dump select rows from a production server to a testing server. The goal is to have a testing server and database that contains the subset of data selected, moreover through a python script, I want the ability to restore the database that original subset after testing and potentially modifying the contents of the database.

From my understanding of pg_dump and pg_restore, the databases that they interact with must be of the same dbname. Moreover, a selection criteria should be made with a the COPY command. Hence, my idea is to have 2 databases in my production server, one with the large set of data and one with the selected set. Then, name the smaller set db 'test' and restore it to the 'test' db in the test server.

Is there a better way to do this considering I don't want to keep the secondary db in my production server and will need to potentially make changes to the selected subset in the future.

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. Read the doc section [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html) and [pg_restore](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgrestore.html) and then update your question with a more focused explanation.

Answer (score 0):

> From my understanding of pg_dump and pg_restore, the databases that they interact with must be of the same dbname.

The databases being worked with only have to have the same name if you are using `--create`.  Otherwise each programs operates in whatever database was specified when it was invoked, which can be different.

The rest of your question is too vague to be addressable.  Maybe pg_dump/pg_restore are the wrong tools for this, and just using COPY...TO and COPY...FROM would be more suitable.